# What is the format of the .tar.gz file for setting up firefox preference from selenium python?

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

What is the format of the .tar.gz file for setting up firefox preference from selenium python?

```
from selenium import webdriver
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk',('application/tgz'))

browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = profile)
```

above code did not work.
Would be fine if someone has tried out it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit googling, I got this you can give a try.

```
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'application/x-gzip')
```

Note that ".tar" has MIME type of `application/x-tar`, "tar.gz,tgz,gz" have `application/x-gzip`.

Also you might also want to add more about:config settings which may affect.

```
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'application/x-gzip')
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", your_download_dir)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
```